# MVC Razor in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

Documentation shows "how easy" it is, but I have to constantly keep adding @: in front of any code within, for example, a For Each.

They say that Razor will "magically" know when code ends and HTML markup starts. Using their examples, just doesn't work without having to add @: everywhere where HTML is.

Can someone explain to me why VB.NET just doesn't want to work with Razor like it's supposed to?

I'm seriously considering forcing all of our developers to switch to C#

Comment: Do you have an example of code where you're having to add `@:` everywhere HTML is?

Comment: Check out the "what not to ask" FAQ: [*"avoid asking subjective questions where your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”"*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Not a rant. Maybe a question in disguise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VB syntax requirement is that HTML markup needs to be prefixed with an @ sign when it is combined with server-side code in a code block. So long as you follow the rules, Razor will be able to parse your code. There's nothing "magical" about it at all.

You might want to show your developers the VB documentation for Razor: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/asp-net-web-pages-visual-basic, although I would support any move to C#...

Comment: Please don't feed the troll. If the OP had a serious question, s/he would have asked it.

Comment: @JDB The VB documentation is hard to find so my guess is that the OP is trying to use Razor in VB based off the C# docs. Therefore the question is in that case valid and explainable - although it might have been worded differently.

Comment: English is not my first language and I'm frustrated that almost all of the VB examples I get doesn't work and I have to figure out how. The code isn't in a code block, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I reckon I might just push for C# because stuff that just works perfectly in it, doesn't in VB.NET